# mysql - Retrieve value from two tables in single query line

Tags: php, mysql

My question may seem very easy to most but it has its own twists. I'll get to the point right away.

I have a PHP code which consists of a MySQL query whose function is to select a column, `product_name` from a table called `products` and then doing some further stuff.

Here's the code:

```
if(isset($_POST["type"]) && $_POST["type"]=='add')
{
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){ 
        $new_product[$key] = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }

    unset($new_product['type']);
    unset($new_product['return_url']); 


    $statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT product_name FROM products WHERE product_code=? LIMIT 1");
    $statement->bind_param('s', $new_product['product_code']);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($product_name);



    while($statement->fetch()){

        $new_product["product_name"] = $product_name; 

        if(isset($_SESSION["cart_products"])){  
            if(isset($_SESSION["cart_products"][$new_product['product_code']]))
            {
                unset($_SESSION["cart_products"][$new_product['product_code']]);
            }           
        }
        $_SESSION["cart_products"][$new_product['product_code']] = $new_product; //update or create product session with new item  
    } 
}
```

Now, what I want is to retrieve data from **two tables**, i.e `products` AND `cat_1`, both have **exactly same column names**. Obviously, the data is different in both the tables. However, I want to retrieve the same column from `cat_1` too, i.e `product_name`.

I have tried using `JOIN` method, but got this error:
`Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in D:\Work\offline\`.

So, is there any way to do this? Any solution will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If they have the same columns use a `UNION` query if a `JOIN` doesn't make sense.

Comment: `$mysqli->prepare` returns false if an error occurred. What did your query look like when you used the `JOIN` method?

Comment: You can use aliases to separate tables with same column names

Answer (score 1):

You should use join here, but, as you have the same column name in both table, you must give alias to make it works:

```
$statement = $mysqli->prepare("
    SELECT 
           products.product_name AS p_product_name,
           cat_1.product_name AS c_product_name 
      FROM products
      JOIN cat_1
        ON --join clause here, maybe products.product_code = cat_1.product_code--
     WHERE products.product_code=? LIMIT 1");

....
$new_product["p_product_name"] = $p_product_name;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

## Yes, the right way to do that is with a join, but the trick is what kind of join you want.

From your description, it is VERY unclear exactly what you're trying to do, so I'll answer your questions as it was asked. Also, `bindParam` always better with named variables (`":pcode"`).

```
$statement = $mysqli->prepare("
    SELECT products.product_name as name, cat_1.product_name as cat_name
    FROM products
    LEFT JOIN cat_1 ON products.product_code = cat_1.product_code
    WHERE products.product_code = :pcode
    LIMIT 1
");
$statement->bindValue(':pcode', $new_product['product_code']. PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->$execute();
```

### No need for `bind_result`, or a loop, since you are limiting to 1 result...

```
$product = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $product ['name'] .':'. $product ['cat_name'] . '\n<br>';
```

### ...but when you need a loop...

```
foreach ( $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $product ) {
    echo $product ['name'] .':'. $product ['cat_name'] . '\n<br>';
}
```

Comment: Your solution is giving birth to another error.
`1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':pcode LIMIT 1' at line 1`

Something is wrong with the syntax.

Comment: did you try echoing the value of `$new_product['product_code']`?